# Invalid value for argument `gte`: input contains invalid characters. Expected ISO-8601 DateTime. (Prisma)

Tags: javascript, sql, prisma

I'm using Prisma with a MySQL database. This is my code:

```
  const thisYear = Number("2023")
  const newYear = thisYear + 1

  const startDate = format(new Date(thisYear, 6, 1), 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss')
  const endDate = format(new Date(newYear, 5, 30), 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss')
  console.log("startDate, endDate: ", startDate, endDate)

  const bucketTransactions = await prisma.bucket_transaction.groupBy({
       by: ['bucket_id'],
       _sum: {
           amount: true,
       },
       where: {
           date_added: {
               gte: startDate,
               lte: endDate,
           },
           amount: {
               gt: 0,
           },
           donation_id: {
               gt: 0,
           },
       },
   });
```

I get this error:

```
Invalid value for argument `gte`: input contains invalid characters. Expected ISO-8601 DateTime.
```

This is the value of startDate and endDate in the console log:

```
startDate, endDate:  2023-07-01 00:00:00 2024-06-30 00:00:00
```

Do you know what's wrong with my code?

I ran this directly into the SQL terminal and it worked:

```
select * from bucket_transaction WHERE date_added BETWEEN "2023-07-01 00:00:00" and "2024-06-30 00:00:00" AND amount > 0 AND donation_id > 0;
```

Why doesn't it work with Prisma?

Comment: Doesn't ISO-8601 require a `T` in the timestamp nowadays? Like `'2023-07-01T00:00:00'`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change

```
const startDate = format(new Date(thisYear, 6, 1), 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss')
```

to

```
const startDate = new Date(thisYear, 6, 1)
```

or

```
const startDate = new Date(thisYear, 6, 1).toISOString()
```

Prisma work with the date directly or with the .toISOString()

Answer (score 0):

I had to change the startDate and the endDate into a new Date object like this:

```
       where: {
           date_added: {
               gte: new Date(startDate),
               lte: new Date(endDate),
           }
       },
```